# Having trouble installing Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I was trying to install Flutter on my VS Code but I kept running into this issue. Android license status unknown.

```
(base) Lenovo-Legion:~/Documents/$ flutter doctor
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Linux, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
    [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
        ✗ Android license status unknown.
          Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
          See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
    [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    [✓] Android Studio
    [✓] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
    [✓] Connected device (1 available)
    
    ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
    (base) Lenovo-Legion:~/Documents/$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
            at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
            at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
            at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
            at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
            at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
            ... 5 more
    (base) Lenovo-Legion:~/Documents/$
```

I went back to Android Studio and updated all the SDK licenses as well. No help. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by going to Android studio> Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools and checking the option to download the Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest).

[Android SDK Command Line Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct278.png)

Then reboot VS Code and re-run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and enter y to accept all licenses. Should work like a charm now!

```
(base) Lenovo-Legion:~/Documents/$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Linux, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
(base) Lenovo-Legion:~/Documents/$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
5 of 6 SDK package licenses not accepted. 100% Computing updates...             
Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)? y

1/5: License android-googletv-license:
---------------------------------------
Terms and Conditions

This is the Google TV Add-on for the Android Software Development Kit License Agreement.
......
......
......
......
```

Check

```
(base) Lenovo-Legion:~/Documents/$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Linux, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• No issues found!
```